# Concat columns in different rows with same ID SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking to concat a column in each row that that holds text input....

I am using SQL Server 2005

The rows look like this

```
Number     Date           Update Time     description
------    -----           -----------    -------------
0123      01/01/2015      01/07/2015     Hello, I want to
0123      01/01/2015      01/01/2015     Concat these columns
```

Hopefully this is easy and I am just being a simpleton

Comment: can you put a expected sample output?

Comment: What you need is something like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function, however SQL*Server does not have one - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server for some solutions (`STUFF` may work best here).

Comment: @Raad STUFF has nothing to do with the actual concatination of the columns, STUFF is a function to replace characters at a position in a varchar

Comment: How would you determine which description should be the first ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - yes, you are correct, however I meant to refer to the answer that uses `STUFF` and now I can't edit my comment =/

Comment: The Expected Output would be 1 Row with the description field concatenated.....

Comment: @SteveDyson there is no row 1, I see 2 rows which cannot be ordered by any column, a solution cannot be garantied to pick the first row on your list as the first row

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I would Like the 2 rows to Become 1 row with the description field Concatenated....  hope this explains it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are dealing free form text, I think it is better to explicitly convert the XML back to a character data type:

```
SELECT t.Number,
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + cast(t2.description AS nvarchar(max) )
              FROM <tablen> t2 
              WHERE t2.Number = t.Number 
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).VALUE('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Description
FROM <table> t
GROUP BY t.Number;
```

This prevents problems with characters such as `&`, `<`, and `>`.

Comment: When i try to run this i get an error of VALUE is not a valid function, property or field

Comment: @SteveDyson . . . That is very strange.  `VALUE` is perfectly valid for the XML data type.

Comment: I have been working on other projects since this but will pick it up again shortly...... Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach:

```
SELECT A.Number, MAX(A.[Date]) AS [Date], MAX(A.[Update Time]) AS [Update Time]
, STUFF((SELECT ' ' + B.description AS [text()] 
    FROM table1 B 
        WHERE A.Number = B.Number 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS Description
FROM  table1 A
GROUP BY A.Number
```

Comment: Thank You John, i will give this a try.... Can i also use a where clause on the Date because i need to filter by another field that has either Open or Closed in it...

Comment: Not completely sure of what you mean. But because it's matching on the Number field, as long as you filter the outer select with the data you need first with a `WHERE` clause then you'll be fine.